# Flutter Rebuild Just One Row in ListView

Tags: listview, flutter, listviewitem, setstate, rebuild

I have one listview in my app. Each row has some buttons that affect only that same row. I don't want to refresh whole `Listview`. When I call `setState()` on tapping buttons, that causes the whole `Listview` to refresh.

How to do refreshing on just the same row of tapping buttons inside the row?

In my code tapping on a button must cause a change color of the same button:

```
....
....
....

List<mPlay> playList = new List();

....
....
....

@override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return new Directionality(
        textDirection: globals.textDirection,
        child: new Scaffold(
            key: globalKey,
            body: (playList != null && playList.length > 0)
                ? new SmartRefresher(
                    headerBuilder: _buildHeader,
                    enablePullDown: true,
                    enablePullUp: true,
                    onRefresh: _onRefresh,
                    onOffsetChange: _onOffsetCallback,
                    child: new ListView.builder(
                      padding: const EdgeInsets.all(0),
                      itemCount: playList.length,
                      itemBuilder: (context, i) {
                        return _buildRow(playList[i], i);
                      },
                    ))
                : EmptyWidget()));
  }

  Widget _buildRow(mPlay play, int index) {
  return new Card(
        child: new Container(
        child: new Row(children: <Widget>[
        new InkWell(
                            child: new IconButton(
                                icon: Icon(
                                  Icons.group_add,
                                  color: play.isContributed == "1"
                                      ? Colors.blueAccent
                                      : Colors.black,
                                ),                                
                                onPressed: () {
                                  play.isContributed =
                                      play.isContributed == "0" ? "1" : "0";
                                  setState(() {
                                    playList[index].isContributed =
                                        play.isContributed;
                                  });
                                }))
        ])
        ))


  }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to use state management methods like scope model, BLoC, redux. [Checkout this post to get a proper idea](https://medium.com/flutter-community/let-me-help-you-to-understand-and-choose-a-state-management-solution-for-your-app-9ffeac834ee3)

Comment: Are you able to provide some example code? That'd improve the long-term usefulness of your answer and would help more people.

Answer (score 0):

I encountered the same problem. I worked it out as following steps:

1. create a streamController
2. judge & assign the streamController to a row which will be refreshed later
3. call streamController.add(...) to refresh the row.

below is a sample code:

in ListView builder

```
        return ListView.builder(
                    itemCount: 100,
                    itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {
                        return CMyListViewRow(index == _iSelectedRowIndex ? _streamCtlBet : null);
                    });
```

and in CMyListViewRow, you do like below:

```
       if( _streamController != null ){
            return StreamBuilder(
                initialData: 0,
                stream: _streamController.stream,
                builder: (BuildContext context, AsyncSnapshot<int> snapshot) {
                    return _getRow();
                });
        }
        else{
            return _getRow();
        }
```